# Deploying Hapi.js app to AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hapi.js

I am trying to deploy an app made in Hapi.js to AWS EC2 but I am unable to find any help online.

The app works perfect on localhost (I'm using Postman) but after deploying, I can't get a response to the requests even after I can see the server running in SSH/PuTTY.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what response are you getting? there's always 'a' response, whether it's a request timeout, 200, 500, 502, etc.

Comment: Did you open the security group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
I had placed my routes in a separate file and had it registered in server.js.

For some reason I cannot comprehend, Hapi could not find the routes after I deployed the, while it worked perfectly on localhost.

Just moved all the routes in server.js, and it started working.